# Rails ActiveRecord: Locking down specific association when record enters a particular state

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766138/rails-activerecord-locking-down-attributes-when-record-enters-a-particular-state) asked about attributes, but I would like to extend the question to associations.

Say I have a simple blogging model

```
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :discussion
end
```

Discussion has a #closed? boolean state.  I would like to block **all** entry points to add more comments to a closed discussion.  For example,

```
discussion.comments << Comment.new
discussion.comments.create(:text => 'Something')
```

and any others that may exist...

Thanks,

-Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding validation method to `Comment` model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :discussion

  def validate
    errors.add_to_base("Discussion is closed!") if discussion.closed? && new_record?  
  end
end
```

This validation will prevent from adding new comments to discussion, but will allow editing of existing comments on already closed discussion.